# Should you remove __future__ imports and unicode strings when upgrading to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have been in the process of upgrading code bases to Python 3. One thing I've been doing is running `2to3` and seeing what the script suggests. Something it continually suggests is to remove all `__future__` imports as well as any unicode strings e.g. `u"python2 unicode str"` (which makes sense to me, since Python 3 strings are unicode by default).

From what I can tell, these changes do not alter the functionality of the code in any way - it seems to just be "clean up". Is that correct? Is there any reason to keep the `__future__` imports and unicode strings? Any explicit reason to remove them?

Note: I don't care about keeping Python 2 compatibility - it's out of support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to remove them, nor any strong reason to keep them. They're [guaranteed to remain available, but do nothing, on Python versions that enable them by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html):

> MandatoryRelease records when the feature became part of the language; in releases at or after that, modules no longer need a future statement to use the feature in question, but may continue to use such imports.
>
> No feature description will ever be deleted from `__future__`

If you're sure you'll never run on Python 2, it doesn't really matter what you do.

Comment: Cool - thank you! In that case I'll probably remove them for clean up since they aren't doing anything and don't care about Python 2 going forward.